# How to export data of WebDataGridview to an existing Excel sheet?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, infragistics

I have a Webdatagridview and i want to export the data of it(header not included because my excel file already have header) to my Existing Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 protected void ExportToExcel()
 {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=YourFiles.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;

        System.IO.StringWriter sr = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw= new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sr);

        gvFiles.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I encounter error: {"Script control 'ctl00' is not a registered script control. Script controls must be registered using RegisterScriptControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().\r\nParameter name: scriptControl"}

Comment: you must include `ScriptManager` in your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Infragistics WebDataGrid, you can use the WebExcelExporter and use an overload for the [Export](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Web.v11.2~Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.WebExcelExporter~Export.html) method that takes and instance of a workbook or worksheet.

For preventing the headers set the ShowHeader property of the WebDataGrid that you are exporting to false before calling Export.  Note that this will not need to be set back to true since the response is being changed to send the excel file to the client so there is no state information for the grid sent to the client for this request.